# laravel долго выполняются тесты перед push

Tags: laravel, phpunit

Сейчас на проекте больше 150 тестов с посевом тестовых данных в БД.
Настроили всем сотрудникам pre-push, чтобы в случае если тесты провалены ветка не пушилась. 
Проблема в том что тесты выполняются 5 минут сейчас, и в ближайшем будующем эта цифра будет значительно расти.

Какими способами решается данная задача, чтобы сотрудник не сидел и не ждал пока его ветка пушнется.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема обычно решается добавлением тестов в CI(Continuous integration), то есть когда тесты прогоняются на отдельных серверах. Собирается билд, прогоняются тесты и результат куда то выводится.

На гитхабе например, есть так называемые [Action'ы](https://github.com/features/actions). Они выполняются на каждый push в pull request. То есть ты можешь сколько угодно изменять код в своей ветке, но если из этой ветки создан pull request, то прогоняются тесты и результат выводится в пул реквест, соответственно если например тесты не проходят, то смержить такой pull request нельзя.

Соответственно, если вы работаете по git flow то запушить изменения в develop или master ветки напрямую нельзя(только через pull request).

Интеграционные и приемочные тесты требуют много зависимостей, по этому часто очень долго выполняются. По этому стоит отдавать предпочтение модульному тестированию(тестирование класса в изоляции).